# How to use TFS Build/Release Steps "Cloud Based Load Test" & "Cloud based web performance test" for On-Premise URLS ?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In Build or release in TFS 2017 below are steps available to be added, How these steps could be used to run On-Premise URLs.
Its working fine with Public url but its failing in on-premise urls.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The Cloud-based Load Testing (CLT) service can be used for performance
>   and scale testing of an app by generating load from Azure. This type
>   of load generation **can only access and generate load on an
>   Internet-located or publicly accessible app**.

If you want  to load test apps or sites that are only available to your company, such as internal or pre-release apps, staging or preproduction deployments. You should refer the tutorials in [**Testing private and intranet applications using cloud-based load testing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/clt-behind-firewall).

Usually use below two scenarios:

- *Use an ARM template to deploy load agents with static IPs*
- *Use an ARM template to deploy load agents in a VNet*